# Intersection in an array of rectangles OpenCv

Tags: opencv, detection, intersection

I try to detect certain moving objects in a video. If any two/three+ rectangles overlap/intersect I want them to change the color.
I have tried something like this:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0);
            // intersection
            original = boundRect[i];
                for (size_t j = 0; j < boundRect.size(); j++){
                  if (j == i) continue; // the same rectangle
                  match = boundRect[j];
                  if ((original & match).area() > 0) color = Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 255.0);
                  else color = Scalar(0.0, 255.0, 0.0);
                }
                // draw the rectangle
                rectangle(frame, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
        }
```

It does work sometime, but now always. I don't know if I am doing it right or if there is any better way to do that.

Comment: you overwrite the color for each j... just remove the else case

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. Problem solved.

Comment: @Micka You should post this as an answer so the question shows up as answered.

Comment: @SSteve I will, but not from mobile phone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to compute intersects the right way, but you only draw the results once for each `i`. And if a rectangle `j` doesn't intersect `i` you'll overwrite your changed color again. Just remove the `else` case for setting the color, OR remember whether (or how often) a rectangle intersects another one. For example:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        int nIntersections = 0;
        // intersection
        original = boundRect[i];
            for (size_t j = 0; j < boundRect.size(); j++){
              if (j == i) continue; // the same rectangle
              match = boundRect[j];
              if ((original & match).area() > 0)
              {
                  nIntersections++;
                  // if you only want to know whether intersections appear or not, you can stop the inner for-loop here, by using j=boundRect.size(); continue; or break;
              }
            }
            // draw the rectangle
            cv::Scalar color(0,255,0);
            if(nIntersections > 0) color = cv::Scalar(0,0,255);
            // adjust for different 
            // if(nIntersections > 1) color = ...
            rectangle(frame, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0);
            // for simplicity you can just call rectangle(frame, boundRect[i], color, 2, 8, 0); without getting top-left and bottom-right points first. cv::rectangle uses cv::Rect as a parameter directly if you like.
    }
```

if you however want to draw each intersection area, it's getting a bit more complicated, but can be done, too...